# Plantin Small Caps

Tags: fonts, small-caps

Is there a version of the font Plantin with small capitals? And if so, is this available for download anywhere?

I got Plantin with Sibelius 7 and it comes with regular, italic, bold, and bold italic, but no small capitals.

Thanks.

Comment: Both the versions you can buy i.e. from Linotype and MyFonts.com include small caps. The question seems to be off topic though...